# Delay method after input/stop receiving input

Tags: android

So I'm trying to create a trivia like quiz game where two people can play head-to-head on the same phone. Everything is perfect except for when you select an answer it generates the next question so fast the other person ends up hitting a random answer.

For example, if both players go to hit the button almost at the same time, the slight second between the first and second it generates a new question and the second player ends up clicking a random answer for a different random question.

Can anyone help me understand how to delay the next question after an answer is selected, and for the buttons to stop receiving input while this delay is occurring?

Code is below, but really I just need to know what direction to head, doesn't need to be specifically for my code.

Thanks,

```
public class DuelMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

Button answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, playAgain, returnHome, answer1p2, answer2p2, answer3p2, answer4p2;
TextView score, question, question2, score2;
private MultiplyQuestions mQuestions = new MultiplyQuestions();
private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mScore2 = 0;
private int mQuestionLength = mQuestions.mQuestions.length;
Random rng = new Random();
TextView mTextField, timer2;
CountDownTimer gameTimer;
boolean gameTimerIsRunning;
TextView correctFade;



public void startGame(){
    startGameTimer();

}


public void startGameTimer(){
    gameTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {


        @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("Time Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            timer2.setText("Time Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override public void onFinish() {
            gameTimerIsRunning = false;
            gameOver();

        }

    };
    gameTimer.start();
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_duel_menu);

    answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);

    answer1p2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1p2);
    answer2p2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2p2);
    answer3p2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3p2);
    answer4p2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4p2);

    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    score2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score2);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    question2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question2);

    timer2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer2);
    mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    correctFade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctFade);

    score.setText("Score "  + mScore);
    score2.setText("Score " + mScore2);


    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/Monster.ttf");
    score.setTypeface(custom_font);
    score2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    question.setTypeface(custom_font);
    question2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    mTextField.setTypeface(custom_font);
    timer2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    answer1p2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    answer2p2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    answer3p2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    answer4p2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    answer1.setTypeface(custom_font);
    answer2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    answer3.setTypeface(custom_font);
    answer4.setTypeface(custom_font);

    Button advanceToDuelFriend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgain);
    advanceToDuelFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View agr0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DuelMenu.this, DuelMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button advanceToHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnHome);
    advanceToHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View agr0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DuelMenu.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    final Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeoutcorrect);


    updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
    startGame();


    answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore++;
                score.setText("Score " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            } else {
                mScore--;
                score.setText("Score " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            }

        }

    });

    answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore++;
                score.setText("Score " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            } else {
                mScore--;
                score.setText("Score " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            }

        }
    });

    answer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore++;
                score.setText("Score " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            } else {
                mScore--;
                score.setText("Score " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            }

        }
    });

    answer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer4.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore++;
                score.setText("Score " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));

            } else {
                mScore--;
                score.setText("Score " + mScore);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            }

        }
    });




    answer1p2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer1p2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore2++;
                score2.setText("Score " + mScore2);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            } else {
                mScore2--;
                score2.setText("Score " + mScore2);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            }

        }

    });

    answer2p2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer2p2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore2++;
                score2.setText("Score " + mScore2);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            } else {
                mScore2--;
                score2.setText("Score " + mScore2);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            }

        }
    });

    answer3p2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer3p2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore2++;
                score2.setText("Score " + mScore2);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            } else {
                mScore2--;
                score2.setText("Score " + mScore2);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            }

        }
    });

    answer4p2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer4p2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore2++;
                score2.setText("Score " + mScore2);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));

            } else {
                mScore2--;
                score2.setText("Score " + mScore2);
                updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            }

        }
    });






}

private void updateQuestion(int num) {



    Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(DuelMenu.this, R.anim.enter);
    question.startAnimation(fadeIn);

    fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

    });

    question.setText(mQuestions.getQuestion(num));
    answer1.setText(mQuestions.getChoice1(num));
    answer2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice2(num));
    answer3.setText(mQuestions.getChoice3(num));
    answer4.setText(mQuestions.getChoice4(num));

    question2.setText(mQuestions.getQuestion(num));
    answer1p2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice1(num));
    answer2p2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice2(num));
    answer3p2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice3(num));
    answer4p2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice4(num));


    mAnswer = mQuestions.getCorrectAnswer(num);


}



protected void gameOver() {
    gameTimer.cancel();

    if (mScore > mScore2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 Wins ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (mScore < mScore2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 2 Wins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (mScore == mScore2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "IT'S A TIE!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    playAgain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgain);
    playAgain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    returnHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnHome);
    returnHome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

public void quitToMenu(View view) {
    gameTimer.cancel();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));


}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer, I just built a method with a timer and put the method that displays the questions inside the timer. I also made the buttons go invisible while ticking and back visible when finished.

If there is a better way to do this please let me know, till then this will suffice!

method I used below.

```
public void startGameTimer2(){
    answer1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    answer2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    answer3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    answer4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    answer1p2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    answer2p2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    answer3p2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    answer4p2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    gameTimer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {


        @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        }

        @Override public void onFinish() {
            gameTimerIsRunning = false;
            updateQuestion(rng.nextInt(mQuestionLength));
            answer1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            answer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            answer3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            answer4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            answer1p2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            answer2p2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            answer3p2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            answer4p2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    };
    gameTimer.start();
}
```